# Accessing variables using a for loop in HTML (python flask)

Tags: python, html, flask

```
class fruit(flaskform):
fruit1 = "apple"
fruit2 = "orange"
fruit3 = "grapes"
```

I am trying to access the variables in a for loop in my html page.

```
{% for index in range(3) %}
    {{"fruit" + index}}
{%endfor%}
```

Is this possible? I would like to avoid writing 100 lines of code to access the variables if I have 100 fruits. I am new to flask and html. My question could be unclear and feel free to ask me if more info is needed.

Comment: Try a `list` of fruit names instead.

Comment: class fruit(flaskform):
fruit = ["apple", "orange", "graps"]

in HTML:
{% for index in range(3) %} {{"fruit" + index}} {%endfor%}

Like this?

Comment: @calvert Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store your fruits in a list like this:

```
fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'grapes']
```

Then, you can use a for loop in Jinja2 to iterate through your list and display each individual item.

```
{% for fruit in fruits %}
    {{ fruit }}
{% endfor %}
```